Dolphin Services vanished after upgrade to Kubuntu 24.10
Does Dolphin on plasma 6.1 still support dolphin services? My installed services are no longer available after upgrade.

Moving the respective .desktop files from ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ to ~/.local/share/kio/servicemenus/ did the trick.
I had to create the latter folder.
